# Passing an array to a function - Different values - Segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk

I have the following code:

```
gpointer w[3];
GtkWidget *menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new();
w[0] = menu_item;
menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new();
w[1] = menu_item;
GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);
w[2] = buffer;
```

This is all good till now. Let's now connect a signal:

```
g_signal_connect(w[0], "activate", G_CALLBACK(runner), w);
```

`runner` function is declared as:

```
void runner(gpointer root, gpointer w[]);
```

Testing the values of `w` array before entering `runner` and while in it shows that they (the values) are different. I need them to be the same. How can I accomplish that, and why they aren't identical? Also, segfault occurs.

---

I created a small program that is bare bones of the original one and that is supposed to recreate the conditions such that the problem occurs. Oddly enough, it runs fine.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void carry(gpointer root, gpointer a[])
{
        g_print("\n");                                                              
        g_print("%d\n", root);
        g_print("%d\n", a[0]);                                                      
        g_print("%d\n", a[1]);
        g_print("%d\n", a[2]);                                                      
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);                                                     

        GtkWidget *menu_item;
        GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
        gpointer abc[3];

        menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new();
        abc[0] = menu_item;
        g_print("%d\t%d\n", menu_item, abc[0]);
        menu_item = gtk_menu_item_new();
        abc[1] = menu_item;
        g_print("%d\t%d\n", menu_item, abc[1]);                                     
        buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new(NULL);                                         
        abc[2] = buffer;                                                            
        g_print("%d\t%d\n", buffer, abc[2]);

        g_signal_connect(abc[2], "modified-changed", G_CALLBACK(carry), abc);       

        gtk_text_buffer_set_modified(abc[2], TRUE);

        gtk_main();

        return 0;
}
```

Which means that something else is problematic. I'll try something else now, like commenting lines and leaving only the relevant ones.

---

I didn't comment any lines yet, but I tried putting `g_print` in both the caller and the callee.

This is an output:

```
1162863440  1162863440
1162864736  1162864736
1163320992  1163320992

1162863440
-2
1162668992
973486176
```

The first three lines compare the original values with their copies in the array (in the sense of `g_print("%d\t%d\n", menu_item, abc[0]);` from the code above). As you can see, everything is assigned correctly. After a new line, we check those same values in the callee. `root`, the first parameter, always has the correct value. So there's no problem with that. `abc[0]` in the callee **always** has the value of *-2*. Seriously, every time I run the program it is *-2*. Other two (`abc[1]` and `abc[2]`) always have some garbage random values, but they change every time I run the program unlike `abc[0]`.

I hope this will help in diagnosing and fixing the problem.

Comment: `w[2] = buffer;` but `buffer` isn't initialized.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh yeah, I forgot to add that. It won't solve the problem, though.

Comment: There's not really enough here to reproduce the problem. Have you stepped through in your debugger to look for probable causes?

Comment: @tadman So everything looks fine, huh? I thought so. I included only information I thought is relevant for the problem. Unfotunately, I'm not really good with debuggers. I mean, I can debug a CLI program but not the GUI one ('cause when GUI starts I lose the control in the debugger and get it back only when GUI terminates). Do you (or anyone else) have any idea what could be the cause of this problem? Please tell me and I'll include it in the question, but I can't include it just like that since I can't for the life of me find anything that is suspicious in my code.

Comment: If you're debugging a GUI app, just drop a breakpoint a line or two before the problem.  When execution hits the breakpoint, it'll hand control back to the debugger, at which point you can inspect variable, single step, etc etc etc.

Comment: @dgnuff Thanks. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried passing both `abc[0]` and `abc` normally through a function (`func(arg0, arg1, ...)` instead of using `g_signal_connect()`) and **there is no problem whatsoever**.

This all can mean only one thing: `g_signal_connect` is messing with my values. It changes them for some unknown reason.

I guess I'll have to use a struct.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use `gpointer`s everywhere. A `gpointer` is a `void *`, so you're pretty much disabling all the type checking the compiler could do for you. Use `GtkWidget *` instead, and do proper casts using `G_OBJECT()`, `GTK_TEXT_BUFFER()` etc. macros.

You should also use typed callback arguments, as they appear in the documentation for each signal. For example for the `activate` signal:

```
void
user_function (GtkMenuItem *menuitem,
               gpointer     user_data)
```

And if you want to pass several items in the user-data field, pass a pointer or pointer to a structure instead of an array of pointers.

And if you have a segfault, well, just use a debugger to check where the problem is.